# $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta),$ for some $ \alpha $ and $\beta$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15})$ be a extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, i need to show the elements of  $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15})\mid\mathbb{Q})$ the Galois group asociate to this extension, i know that is enogth knowing were the root of the minimal polynimials of $\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10}$ and $\sqrt{15}$ are asigned, to create the automorphisms, but i had notice that $\sqrt{6}=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{2},\sqrt{10}=\sqrt{5}\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{15}=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{5}$, my question is, there is a way to show that the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15})$ is of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$ for some $\alpha,\beta$ depending of $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{5}$, any clue?

Comment: One way you could show this is via the proof of the primitive element theorem.

Comment: And indeed, geometric considerations show that for any “random” element $\beta$ of your field $K$, $K=\Bbb Q(\beta)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, 
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10},\sqrt{15})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$ because $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{10}=2\sqrt{15}$ implies $\sqrt{15} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6},\sqrt{10})$.